# Multiple conditional joins in a stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a search procedure that we're converting from dynamic SQL. We're close to finishing but we have one issue.

We have a bunch of criteria fields that may or may not be supplied by the user.  If they are NOT supplied we want to ignore the table completely. If they are supplied, we need to JOIN to the table.

In dynamic SQL, we would build a large dynamic SQL statement and append them all together for execution. So it would like this:

```
IF @bColorMatch = 1  
   SET @sqlFROM = @sqlFROM + '
            JOIN tProductColors ON tProducts.pid=tProductColors.pid  '

   SET @sqlWHERE = @sqlWHERE + '  
            AND tProductColors.pc_color like ''blue'' '
```

Now that we have eliminated dynamic SQL, we're trying something along these lines. I know we cannot do this but we're looking for something similar to this logic.

```
SELECT 
    p.pid, p.model, pc.pc_color
FROM 
    tProducts
    CASE @bColorMatch
         WHEN 1
            THEN JOIN tProuductColors 
                ON tProducts.pid=tProductsColors.pcid
                   AND pc_Color like '%blue%'
    END
```

I know that I could put the ENTIRE statement into a large switch and just write two of them. One when the variable is true that includes the JOIN and when for when it does not. However, there are a dozen of these criteria fields in a single call. It would be impractical to loop that many possibilities.

We would just LEFT JOIN to all of the tables but there is just so much overhead going out to the tables if we don't have to. Is there another way around this?

Comment: You could try joining `... on @bColorMatch = 1 and tProducts.pid = tProductsColors.pcid and pc_Color like '%blue%'` with `option ( recompile )` and check the actual execution plan to see of the query optimizer is clever enough to omit the join as appropriate.

Comment: This is one of the (many) cases where using Entity Framework with the `IQueryable` support really shines - would makes this a snap. In T-SQL, without dynamic SQL, this is a nightmare to implement ...

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic example doesn't appear to add `pc_color` to the select list.  If you don't need it then you could create a `WHERE` condition using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT p.pid, p.model
FROM tProducts p 
WHERE @bColorMatch = 0 OR EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM tProuductColors
    WHERE pcid = p.pid
    AND pc_Color = 'blue'
)
```

I set up a test with 8 `tProducts` and 8 `tProuductColors` to get an actual execution plan and there appears to be no overhead when `@bColorMatch = 0`.  here are the results:

#### `@bColorMatch = 0` actual execution plan

[image: @bColorMatch = 0 actual execution plan]

#### `@bColorMatch = 1` actual execution plan

[image: @bColorMatch = 1 actual execution plan]